# Vue code not updating in my Django/Vue Project

Tags: django, vue.js, vuetify.js

I added VueJS to my Django project using [this guide](https://github.com/michaelbukachi/django-vuejs-tutorial/wiki/Django-Vue.js-Integration-Tutorial).

I am now trying to change the example to some code made by me, but nothing changes:
**assets/js/components/Demo.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>

        <p>This is just a Demo.</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

If i change this code, for example, to:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1> test </h1>
        <p>TEST.</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I will keep seeing the first snippet of code, in my frontend.

Here is my **index.js**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');

import Vue from 'vue';
import Demo from "./components/Demo.vue";

    window.Vue = Vue;
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            Demo
        }
    });
```

And here is my Django template, from where Vue is called:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Django Vue</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>

    <div id="app">
        <demo></demo>
    </div>
    {% render_bundle 'main' %}
</body>
</html>
```

The other parts of my Vue/JS code are basically the same of this repository, since i followed the guide https://github.com/michaelbukachi/django-vuejs-tutorial

Am i missing something in my console, maybe? Should i update in some way my JS/Vue code? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
    const app = new Vue({
        render: (h) => h(Demo)
    });
    app.$mount('#app')
```

and change

```
    <div id="app">
        <demo></demo>
    </div>
```

to `<div id="app"></div>`

Comment: Hey, i tried this, but the template in Demo.vue is not showing in index.html

Comment: I suspect your bundles are not loading correctly. Do you see any errors in console about 404?

Comment: Yeah this is what's weird. No, i'm not seeing any error at all in my console. I followed the guide step by step